VSCode python debugger always activates base env on top of selected interpreter with anaconda
After setting up Anaconda and VSCode on my new Mac and selecting my desired python interpreter (in this case called lotteryfl), it seems that a new terminal always starts with a base env activated on top of lotteryfl. This also applies when I try to start the debugger, so that my installed packages in lotteryfl cannot be found when being imported. How may I fix it so that only lotteryfl is activated?


Does this answer your question? How can I debug a python code in a virtual environment using VSCode?

You've probably ran these codes once with base environment selected as the interpreter. Delete '.vscode' folder in your workspace and go to 'Select Interpreter' and select your lotteryfl python environment.

Hi @nigh_anxiety, thanks for the reference! The answer to this question is definitely helpful - I added "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}", to my launch.json file and the debugger can now start and recognizes the packages I installed to lotteryfl! However, the two environments issue still exist, but it's a workaround for sure!

Thank you for the helpful information @Zain! Unfortunately, deleting .vscode in my project folder and select the interpreter again does not solve this two activated env issue :(

How do you install packages for an environment? You need to figure out where you are installing it and which environment you are using.

@JialeDu Thank you for your comment! Currently, since VSCode always activates base on top of lotteryfl, I use terminal to conda activate lotteryfl to activate lotteryfl only and install packages there to ensure they are installed to lotteryfl.

@HangChen Do any of the answers on this post help?  You might have to set the "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true setting.  I don't believe there is a way to force the terminal to always be be in virtual-environment-activated state. But it can be set to the correct default.  I mostly have issues when returning yo a previous session where the terminal is loaded from history.

I had the same problem, and I just opened my ~/.bashrc file and added this code.
correct_env="spot"
curr_conda_env=$(conda info --envs | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}')
if [ "$curr_conda_env" != "$correct_env" ]; then
    echo "Current environment: '$curr_conda_env'"
    echo "Activating '$correct_env' environment"
    conda deactivate
    conda deactivate
    conda deactivate
    conda deactivate
    conda activate $correct_env
fi

In your case you can change correct_env="spot" -> correct_env="lotteryfl"
The multiple conda deactivate commands are likely overkill, but if it works it works.

I had the same issue and I could solve it by selecting directly my conda environment with the VSCode's command palette:
(1) To open the command palette type (Ctrl+Shift+p).
(2) Type "Select Interpreter". After that you should see the conda environments that you have created.
(3) Select the one you want to work with and run the debugger. The VSCode debugger should now use the chosen environment.
(Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

For me how I solve this issue

press ctrl+shift+p
select python:select Interpreter
use the Global option

